# can we copy and move images to another folder using startactivityforresult

Tags: java, android, android-intent, image-gallery, startactivityforresult

I am a newbie in android app development. I have a simple question. I googled about it but couldn't find any satisfactory answer. My question is :
 **Can we copy and move images to another folder using startactivityforresult() method. If yes, then how can we pass the position of the selected images we want to move or copy ?**

Thanks

Comment: copy and move images with  `startactivityforresult() `? Not at all . Read the documentation for `startactivityforresult`.

Comment: Please make the question more clear. From where are you trying to move the image and what image "position" are you referring to? RecyclerView?

Comment: gridview position, trying to move image from one folder to another @Vijai

Comment: So you want the position to be passed to another activity with startActivityForResult(intent), move file in that activity and set result to the calling activity? @Amy

Comment: yes , and move file to the folder which is selected in another activity @Vijai

Comment: If the sole purpose of the other activity is just to move the file, why not just create a method in the activity in question itself to move?

Comment: well, that is not the sole purpose of other activity, other activity is where I have all folders and main activity is where I have all photos in a folder @Vijai

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162802/discussion-between-amy-and-vijai).

Comment: `can we copy and move images to another folder` As your other post this post is again misleading as you are not referring to folders on the file system but to folders in your gridview or those delivered by the media store. You should have started this post and subject with it. It was already unclear in your first post. You changed nothing.

Answer (score 1):

In your main activity:

1. Create new ArrayList to hold selected images:

   `ArrayList<Model_images> selectedImages = new ArrayList<Model_Images>();`
2. Add all selected images to `selectedImages` in your adapter's
   onClick using:

   `selectedImages.add(al_images.get(position));`
3. Then once you have the list of selected images, Build the intent and
   call the activity:

   ```
   Intent moveIntent = new Intent(this, MoveActivity.class);
   moveIntent.putExtra("selected_images", selectedImages);
   startActivityForResult(moveIntent, REQUEST_CODE); // REQUEST_CODE is a unique int value within your app for this intent.
   ```
4. Override `onActivityResult` to receive the response:

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)   {  
             super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);  
             // check if the request code is same as what is passed(REQUEST_CODE) 
             if(requestCode==REQUEST_CODE)  
             {  
                     if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                            //The called activity completed successfully. 
                            String message=data.getStringExtra("MESSAGE"); //The message passed along with result
                     }
             }
   }
   ```

In your `MoveActivity` activity:

1. Get the passed ArrayList:

   ```
   ArrayList<model_Images> selectedImages = new ArrayList<Model_Images>(); 
   if(getIntent().getSerializableExtra("selected_images") != null)
          selectedImages = getIntent().getSerializableExtra("selected_images");
   ```
2. Move the images to destination folder:

   ```
   //Move each selected file to destination
   for (Model_Images image : selectedImages{
       File sourceImage = image.getFile(); //returns the image File from model class to be moved.
       File destinationImage = new File("path/to/destination", "filename.extension");
       moveFile(sourceImage, destinationImage);
   }

   //Method to move the file
   private void moveFile(File sourceFile, File destFile) throws IOException {
       if (!sourceFile.exists()) {
           return;
       }

       FileChannel source = null;
       FileChannel destination = null;
       source = new FileInputStream(sourceFile).getChannel();
       destination = new FileOutputStream(destFile).getChannel();
       if (destination != null && source != null) {
           destination.transferFrom(source, 0, source.size());
       }
       if (source != null) {
           source.close();
       }
       if (destination != null) {
           destination.close();
       }
       source.delete();

   }
   ```
3. Set the result to calling activity once done:

   ```
   // Set result back to the calling activity
   Intent intent=new Intent();  
   intent.putExtra("MESSAGE",message);  // Set a message for the calling activity
   setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);  //RESULT_OK represents success result
   finish();//finishing activity
   ```

P.S: handling storage permission is not discussed and is required to read/write.

Comment: I just checked it. getFile() method cannot be resolved. Do I have to define it in Model_images.java ?